# How to rename multiple files reordering name parts and including ordered numbers at the front (bash)

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a list of files in a folder named based on (a) sample name [sometimes with '_1' or '_2' for different individuals]; (b) job id [1-12]; and (c) chromosome number [chrI-chrXXI].

Ex:

```
    8116_1_chrI.vcf  #sample[8116]; jobId[1]; chr[chrI]
    8116_1_chrII.vcf  #sample[8116]; jobId[1]; chr[chrII]
    ...
    CSC0832_1_7_chrVIII.vcf  #sample[CSC0832_1]; jobId[7]; chr[chrVIII]
    CSC0832_1_7_chrXIX.vcf  #sample[CSC0832_1]; jobId[7]; chr[chrXIX]
    ...
    RNF2887_2_12_chrX.vcf  #sample[RNF2887_2]; jobId[2]; chr[chrX]
    RNF2887_2_12_chrXI.vcf  #sample[RNF2887_2]; jobId[2]; chr[chrXI]
    ...
```

Each sample has the same job id number, and separate files for each chromosome.
I am trying to submit a job array, so now I need unique identifiers (job ids) for each single file, and I am trying to rename those by (1) including a unique number in the front; (2) then adding the sample id; (3) and then the chromosome number.

I am trying to do a bash for loop for that, but it is not working. Below is my script:

```
    for FILENAME in `ls $SCRATCH/stickleback/sorelData/indSamplesVcf/splitChr/*.vcf`; do
    ROOTNAME=`basename ${FILENAME%%_*}`
    CHR=`basename ${FILENAME##*_} .vcf`
    for LIST in `seq 279`; do
    cp "$FILENAME" $SCRATCH/stickleback/sorelData/indSamplesVcf/splitCopy/${LIST}_${ROOTNAME}_${CHR}.vcf
    echo "copying $(basename ${FILENAME}) to ${LIST}_${ROOTNAME}_${CHR}.vcf"
    done
    done
```

What I get is a file with unique numbers, but they are always the same sample id, and the same chromosome number:

```
    1_8116_chrIII.vcf
    2_8116_chrIII.vcf
    ...
```

And one thing I noticed is that when I `echo basename ${FILENAME##*_}`, it lists the chromosomes in alphabetical order (because they are in romans). Will that affect the renaming also?

Sorry for the long and silly question, but I am a newbie at this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it helps ...

```
directory=$SCRATCH/stickleback/sorelData/indSamplesVcf/splitChr

list=0
for filename in $directory/*.vcf ; do
    basename=$( basename ${filename} )  # 8116_1_chrI.vcf
    sample=${basename%%_*}              # 8116
    chr=${basename##*_}                 # chrI.vcf
    list=$(( list+1 ))
    cp "$directory/$filename" "$directory/splitCopy/${list}_${sample}_${chr}"
    echo "copying $basename to ${list}_${sample}_${chr}"
done
```

I assume:

- that you want to add an unique ID ($list) to filename
- filename becomes id_sample_chr.extension

I suggest:

- variables of script in **lowercase**
- prefer `$( command )`, no backticks
- do not use `$( ls )`
- use indentations

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had to remove the `$directory` part here though: `cp "$filename" "$directory/splitCopy/${list}_${sample}_${chr}"`. The way it was before it was giving me an error, and I noticed the path was written twice. I also had to edit my filenames before running this script, because the individuals IDs were not coming through, e.g. `CSC0832_1_7_chrXIX.vcf  #sample[CSC0832_1]; jobId[7]; chr[chrXIX]`. I need that first '_1'. So I just did the `rename CSC0832_ 'CSC0832.' CSC0832*.vcf`, and repeated that for each chunk, so this way I had a '.' separating the sample and individual IDs.